How to generate an earth through vispy or load an earth texture image in jpg format on a sphere?
I hope to create a 3D earth scene. I currently have a jpg format image of the earth's surface. This image is valid under html+js and can be loaded directly onto the sphere.
But I just used vispy and don’t know how to implement this function

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

VisPy does not provide any geographic projection transformation functionality. There are examples showing how to load an image onto a texture (on a mesh for example). Otherwise, my SIFT project has some projection code implemented in OpenGL shader code, but is very very complex for the small bit of functionality you're asking for: https://github.com/ssec/sift
